# I installed the pandas package and I'm still getting the same error: No module named 'pandas'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

input:
import pandas

output:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

I installed the package with the command line - `pip3 install pandas`,
my python version is `3.10.7`

The source of the installed panda package:  c:\users\kfirs\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages

Comment: try uninstalling and reinstalling?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. Please read about how to ask a good question and try to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you.

Comment: @logan_9997 already tried still doesn't work

Comment: @itprorh66 okay I'll do it, thanks.

Comment: Did you install `panda` or `pandas`?

Comment: @NickODell pandas

Comment: Are you sure the version of python in which you installed pandas using pip is the version of python from which your script is running?

Comment: @itprorh66 I have only one version of python because I downloaded python in the first time before 1-2 month and I also checked where I installed the pandas and which python version I'm using in intellij so yes I'm sure. but maybe I installed pandas in the right python version but not in the right folder ?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this will help but in the command prompt type pip --version check to make sure you're on a version that is fluent with pandas, don't know much about pandas but I assume you should try and do the same with pandas. My knowledge is limited but try installing on the same drive as python as this could possibly be why things are not working. 3rd sometimes I have issues with windows after installing pip packs so try restarting your pc sometimes my imports right after installing don't work and this usually fixes but only if it's truly installed where it needs to be and the version needed. Hope I could help.

Comment: my pip version is 22.3.1, I tried to restart my computer and it's still doesn't work, maybe do you have more ideas ? thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).